# How to digitally sign a PDF using a certificate from a Certificate Authority (CA) with AWS Key Management Service (KMS)?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

I've developed an application where users can manually put their signatures on PDFs, and it's working well. Now, I'm looking to implement digital signatures using a certificate provided by a Certificate Authority (CA).

I'm exploring options to achieve this without using costly solutions like storing the certificate in CloudHSM. I've heard about using AWS Key Management Service (KMS) for this purpose but I'm unsure about the specific steps involved.

Could someone please guide me on how to digitally sign PDFs using a CA certificate with AWS KMS?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!